# XSLT for grouping flat XML with multiple nested sections

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have flat XML data that I want to transform, by repeating part of the xml within another area.

I have the following XML:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NewDataSet>
    <GUID>
        <Name>Item1</Name>
        <Status>Open</Status>
        <TableId>Table1</TableId>
    </GUID>
    <GUID>
        <Name>Item2</Name>
        <Status>Closed</Status>
        <TableId>Table1</TableId>
    </GUID>
    <GUID>
        <SignOffName>Fred</SignOffName>
        <Location>UK</Location>
        <TableId>Table2</TableId>
    </GUID>
    <GUID>
        <SignOffName>Mary</SignOffName>
        <Location>UK</Location>
        <TableId>Table2</TableId>
    </GUID>
</NewDataSet>
```

Which I need to transform into the following format:
You'll see where the TableId = Table2, they are repeated for the Table1 items.

```
<Instances>
    <Instance>
        <Name>Item1</Name>
        <data>
            <Status>Open</Status>
            <Table>
                <TableRow RowNumber="1">
                  <SignOffName>Fred<SignOffName>
                  <Location>UK</Location>
               </TableRow>
                <TableRow RowNumber="2">
                  <SignOffName>Mary<SignOffName>
                  <Location>UK</Location>
               </TableRow>
            </Table>
        </data>
    </Instance>
    <Instance>
        <Name>Item2</Name>
        <data>
            <Status>Closed</Status>
            <Table>
                <TableRow RowNumber="1">
                  <SignOffName>Fred<SignOffName>
                  <Location>UK</Location>
               </TableRow>
                <TableRow RowNumber="2">
                  <SignOffName>Mary<SignOffName>
                  <Location>UK</Location>
               </TableRow>
            </Table>
        </data>
    </Instance>
</Instances>
```

I have the following XSLT Style Sheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="Items" match="/NewDataSet/*" use="Name"/>

<xsl:template match="/NewDataSet">
    <Instances>
        <xsl:for-each select="*[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('Items', Name)[1])]">
            <Instance>
                <xsl:copy-of select="Name"/>
                <formdata>
                    <data>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="Status"/>
                        <Table>
                            <!-- a row for each member of current group  -->
                            <xsl:for-each select="key('Items', Name)">
                                <TableRow RowNumber="{position()}">
                                    <xsl:copy-of select="SignOffName | Location"/>
                                </TableRow>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </Table>
                    </data>
                </formdata>
            </Instance>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Instances>    
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I expect the following output:

```
<Instances>
    <Instance>
        <Name>Item1</Name>
        <data>
            <Status>Open</Status>
            <Table>
                <TableRow RowNumber="1">
                  <SignOffName>Fred<SignOffName>
                  <Location>UK</Location>
               </TableRow>
                <TableRow RowNumber="2">
                  <SignOffName>Mary<SignOffName>
                  <Location>UK</Location>
               </TableRow>
            </Table>
        </data>
    </Instance>
    <Instance>
        <Name>Item2</Name>
        <data>
            <Status>Closed</Status>
            <Table>
                <TableRow RowNumber="1">
                  <SignOffName>Fred<SignOffName>
                  <Location>UK</Location>
               </TableRow>
                <TableRow RowNumber="2">
                  <SignOffName>Mary<SignOffName>
                  <Location>UK</Location>
               </TableRow>
            </Table>
        </data>
    </Instance>
</Instances>
```

I can't work out how I can access the other items as they are outside of the current group.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't fully understand the logic of your transformation. Couldn't the expected result be produced simply by:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="NewDataSet">
    <Instances>
        <xsl:for-each select="GUID[TableId='Table1']">
            <Instance>
                <xsl:copy-of select="Name"/>
                <data>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="Status"/>
                    <Table>
                        <xsl:for-each select="../GUID[TableId='Table2']">
                            <TableRow RowNumber="{position()}">
                                <xsl:copy-of select="SignOffName | Location"/>
                            </TableRow>                 
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </Table>
                </data>
            </Instance>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Instances>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or even better:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="NewDataSet">
    <xsl:variable name="table">
        <Table>
            <xsl:for-each select="GUID[TableId='Table2']">
                <TableRow RowNumber="{position()}">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="SignOffName | Location"/>
                </TableRow>                 
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Table>
    </xsl:variable>
    <Instances>
        <xsl:for-each select="GUID[TableId='Table1']">
            <Instance>
                <xsl:copy-of select="Name"/>
                <data>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="Status"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$table"/>
                </data>
            </Instance>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Instances>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you! Both are really close to what I wanted. It just seems that the for-each for Table1 only returns the first match.

Comment: Not sure why you would think so. Does this not return the expected result? https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqrbKL

Comment: Apologies I was testing using https://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html and I was only getting the first Item1 returned, I have tried again now and you are right!

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="Items" match="/NewDataSet/*" use="Name"/>

<xsl:template match="/NewDataSet">
 <xsl:variable name="table">
        <Table>
            <xsl:for-each select="GUID[TableId='Table2']">
                <TableRow RowNumber="{position()}">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="SignOffName | Location"/>
                </TableRow>                 
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Table>
    </xsl:variable>
    <Instances>
        <xsl:for-each select="*[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('Items', Name)[1])]">
            <Instance>
                <xsl:copy-of select="Name"/>
                <formdata>
                    <data>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="Status"/>
                         <xsl:copy-of select="$table"/>
                    </data>
                </formdata>
            </Instance>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Instances>    
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You should accept y.arazim's answer. No one could have guessed from your example that there is a need for grouping - in fact, I am not convinced of it even now. In any case, it solved your main problem.

Comment: Agreed! I have accepted y.arazim's answer. I also agree with you points - I have got a working solution - so I am happy - Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Using Powershell :

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$inputFilename = "c:\temp\test.xml"
$outputFilename = "c:\temp\test1.xml"

$docInput = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)

$outputTemplate = @'
<Instances>
</Instances>
'@
$docOutput = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Parse($outputTemplate)
$instances = $docOutput.Root


$guids = $docInput.Descendants("GUID")
$nameGUIDs = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Where($guids, [Func[object,bool]]{ param($x) $x.Element("Name") -ne $null})
$signoffGUIDs = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Where($guids, [Func[object,bool]]{ param($x) $x.Element("SignOffName") -ne $null})

$groupsNames = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::GroupBy($nameGUIDs,  [Func[object,object]]{ param($x) {$x[0].Element('Name').Value; $x[0].Element('Status').Value} })
$groupsSignoffs = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::GroupBy($signoffGUIDs,  [Func[object,object]]{ param($x) {$x[0].Element('SignOffName').Value; $x[0].Element('Location').Value} })

$table = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('Table'))
$rowNum = 1
foreach($groupsSignoff in $groupsSignoffs)
{
   $signOffName = $groupsSignoff.Element('SignOffName').Value
   $location = $groupsSignoff.Element('Location').Value
   $tableId = $groupsSignoff.Element('TableId').Value

   $num = [System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('RowNumber'), $rowNum)

   $row = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('TableRow'), $num)
   $table.Add($row)   

   $signOff = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('SignOffName'), $signOffName)
   $row.Add($signOff)   

   $loc = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('Location'), $location)
   $row.Add($loc)

   $rowNum++   
}

foreach($groupName in $groupsNames)
{
   $name = $groupName.Element('Name').Value
   $status = $groupName.Element('Status').Value
   $tableId = $groupName.Element('TableId').Value

   Write-Host "Name = "$name ",Status = "$status

   $instance = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('Instance'))
   $instances.Add($instance)   

   $xName = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('Name'), $name)
   $instance.Add($xName)   

   $data = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('data'))
   $instance.Add($data)   

   $xStatus = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('Status'), $status)
   $data.Add($xStatus)   

   $data.Add($table)   
}

$docOutput.Save($outputFilename)
```

Results

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Instances>
  <Instance>
    <Name>Item1</Name>
    <data>
      <Status>Open</Status>
      <Table>
        <TableRow RowNumber="1">
          <SignOffName>Fred</SignOffName>
          <Location>UK</Location>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow RowNumber="2">
          <SignOffName>Mary</SignOffName>
          <Location>UK</Location>
        </TableRow>
      </Table>
    </data>
  </Instance>
  <Instance>
    <Name>Item2</Name>
    <data>
      <Status>Closed</Status>
      <Table>
        <TableRow RowNumber="1">
          <SignOffName>Fred</SignOffName>
          <Location>UK</Location>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow RowNumber="2">
          <SignOffName>Mary</SignOffName>
          <Location>UK</Location>
        </TableRow>
      </Table>
    </data>
  </Instance>
</Instances>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your comment, however I have to use XLST for the transformation.

Comment: Sometimes it's appropriate to suggest an alternative technology to solve a problem -- I do it myself on occasions -- but only when the alternative is clearly a better tool for the job.

Comment: It doesn't look like other solutions give the results you are looking for.

Comment: How is the result here different from yours? https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqrbKL

Comment: @y.arazim : What is your output.  You even said I do not understand the logic.  Do you get exactly what the OP asked for?  Do you think with different input that you would get what OP asked for?